# convert RGB image to HSI color space

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, java-io, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to convert RGB image to HSI color space using visual c++ express 2010 and open CV 2.3.1 and have compiling error problem with this. Please can anyone help me with this and I need to know how can I use the matrix to save the values of H,S and I. Thanks in advance.
The codes that I use are.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;

#include "cxcore.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include <highgui.h> 
using namespace cv;

const string openCVpath = string(getenv("ProgramFiles"))+"\\OpenCV-2.3.1\\samples\\c\\";

int main (int, char**) {
    //call image 
    Mat img1 = imread(openCVpath+"image1.jpg");
    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img1.data);

    // To get pixel values of i-th row and j-th cloumn,
    double R,G,B,min,H,S,I;
    int  i,j;
    const double PI= 3.14;
    for(int i = 0;i < img1.rows ;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < img1.cols ;j++){
            B = input[img1.step * j + i ] ;
            G = input[img1.step * j + i + 1];
            R = input[img1.step * j + i + 2];
        }
        // calculate the values of Hue, Saturation and Intensity
        min = R;
        if (G < min)
            min = G;
        if (B < min)
            min = B;
        I = (R+G+B)/3.0;
        S = 1 - min/I;
        if (S == 0.0)
        {
            H = 0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            H = ((R-G)+(R-B))/2.0;
            H = H/sqrt((R-G)*(R-G) + (R-B)*(G-B));
            H = acos(H);
            if (B > G)
            {
                H = 2*PI - H;
            }
            H = H/(2*PI);
        }
    }
     ifstream f("file.txt");  //...in your routine
//};
imshow("Image",img1);

    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the compilation error you are getting?

Comment: This is the compilation error ." Unhandled exception at 0x771fc41f in image coversion.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0037e56c "

Comment: Can you find out, where exactly the exception is occuring? For example by using a debugger? Or by adding some printfs?

Comment: this error said that "open CV error: bad flag <parameter or structure field> <unrecognized or unsupported array type> in unknown function file ..\..\..\modules\core\src\array.cpp "

Comment: I get the same error, if the image file I am using is not present. Can you check, that the path is correct? Maybe by placing the image file in the same folder as the binary?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use this :

```
cvtColor(img_rgb,img_hsv,CV_RGB2HSV);
```

also, see, [OpenCV image conversion from RGB to HSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017538/opencv-image-conversion-from-rgb-to-hsv)

Comment: They may sound same, but technically HSV and HSI are not the same.

HSI is equivalent to HLS. To convert to HSI, you have to use `CV_RGB2HLS`

Comment: I need to convert to HSI color space and it is not the same with HSV and I need to use the values of H, S and I to draw a diagram

Comment: @sgarizvi, HSI is **not** equivalent to HLS.  I = (R+G+B)/3, while L = (max(R, G, B) + min(R, G, B))/2.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Answer (score 0):

I do not get a compilation error. But I needed to make the following changes to get your Programm to run:

```
B = input[img1.step * i + 3*j ] ;
G = input[img1.step * i + 3*j + 1];
R = input[img1.step * i + 3*j + 2];
```

I had to switch `i` and `j` because that is the way opencv organizes the memory. Also, you need to advance 3 bytes per pixel, because of the 3 rgb values.

Move the curly bracket in the next line to the line above `ifstream f("file.txt");`.
Otherwise you would only compute values for the last row of the image.

remove this line (I am not sure, what it is supposed to do):

```
 ifstream f("file.txt");
```

And inside the for loops I added the following just to visualize the result, because so far you are not doing anything the computed results:

```
input[img1.step * i + 3*j ] = 255*H;
input[img1.step * i + 3*j + 1] = 255*S;
input[img1.step * i + 3*j + 2] = I;
```

Comment: The compilation error is "Unhandled exception at 0x771fc41f in image coversion.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0037e56c" image conversion is my project name

Comment: what you mean by "inside the loop you add some thing to visualize the result"? and by the way I add the " ifstream f("file.txt"); " and didn't finish writing the code by mistake I will use it later to write the values of R,G and B in one txt file and after finding the values of H,S and I I also will write them to another txt file. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: at the current state of your program the HSI valus are computed but not used. So in order to see whether the computation succeeds or produces bogus results, I just wrote them back into the image to visualize them as RGB-values. Just a quick check to see if the results are sensible.

Comment: O.k. thanks for the explanation. As I tried to find the error I tried just to load the image and then show it on the screen I face the same error.Could you please check this also. Thanks