# converted RGB image to HSV but still displaying RGB values?

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv

Image is Red traffic light with background around it.

I convert this RGB image into HSV image using cvtColor(RGB,HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV). But when I display converted HSV image using imshow() I can see that it still shows RGB values of pixel.

[image]

While actual hue values of this region are in range of 0 to 10.

[image]
 Why does this happen?

I am using Qt 5.2.1 in ubuntu, OpenCV version 2.4.9

Comment: please post the code you use to do the ouputs

Comment: imshow interprets every 3 channel Mat as BGR and every 1 channel Mat as grayscale. It doesnt handle color spaces and doesnt have information about color space of the image (which isnt saved anywhere)

Comment: @Micka thanks for information. who converts hsv values to rgb values for imshow()?. does this conversion uses any algorithm?

Comment: cvtColor(hsvImage,outputMat,COLOR_HSV2BGR)

Comment: See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017764/3911355